# Replacing multiple words in a string

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace certain words in a query string, this code will work only if I use 1 line but when I try to use 2 or more it causes issues with my foreach loop, can I combine all my replace operations in 1 line

```
$query = str_replace('','+',$query); // Replaces white space with +
$query = str_replace('and','&',$query); // Replaces and with &
$query = str_replace('not','-',$query); // Replaces not with -
$query = str_replace('or','|',$query);  // Replaces or with |
```

Here is my foreach loop

```
foreach($jsonObj->d->results as $value)
    {   $i = 0;
        $bingArray[str_replace ($find, '', ($value->{'Url'}))] = array(         
    'title'=> $value->{'Title'},
    'score' => $score--
     );
```

I have a str_replace in the foreach loop, thats where I'm getting the error

Comment: show the foreach loop please

Comment: Please don't and start using prepared statements (mysqli/pdo). If you insist then I shall say that you will fail since there are so much obfuscation methods to get around this :) Also note that str_replace accepts an array as search/replace (for a oneliner :p)

Comment: Whilst you can use arrays as the parameters to str_replace(), that will not solve your problem, as functionally it does the same thing, I think you will find there is something else up here. Please show some more code.

Comment: here is my foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create array of search and replace words/characters and pass it to `str_replace`.

```
$search = array('','and','not','or');
$replace= array('+','&','-','|');
$query = str_replace($search,$replace,$query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `str_replace` to do this:

```
$a1= array("", "and", "not", "or");
$a2= array("+", "&", "-", "|");


$result= str_replace($a1, $a2, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use arrays instead of strings in `str_replace`:

```
$query = str_replace(array(' ', 'and', 'not', 'or'), array('+', '&', '-', '|'), $query);
```

You can also save the arrays first in variables, and then pass them to `str_replace`

more details about `str_replace` : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php